# Apache Echarts - Create drag and drop effect

Tags: javascript, charts

i need to do this effect in my project but i've no idea about it. Can you help me?
I've created the chart, but the effects i don't know to do.
[image: Chart]

Here is the real case:
https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/egie3

I've created the chart:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main" style="width: 100%;height:400px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
        var option = {
            title: {
                text: 'VARIAÇÃO DE ENTRADA DE NOTA'
            },
            tooltip: {

            },
            legend: {
                data: ['Valor']
            },
            xAxis: {
                data: ["01/08/20", "05/08/20", "15/08/20", "30/08/20", "02/09/20", "01/10/20"]
            },
            yAxis: {
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Valor',
                type: 'line',
                data: [19.99, 20.5, 21.6, 18.6, 15.1, 22.5],
                tension
            }]
        };

        // use configuration item and data specified to show chart
        myChart.setOption(option);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If somebody knows how to do this effect in chart.js, it's valid.
Thanks!